# How to automatically simulate(define) a mouse dragged event by program instead of mouse

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouse, awtrobot

Could I simulate a mouse dragged event? I Have a custom view which extends from JPanel,  and I added a mouseMotionListener which implements mouseDragged method for it. Now, I want to define (new) a mouse dragged event for this component so that it can act like being dragged, instead of really using mouse. 
I have search MouseEvent class in Oracle.com, but I'm not able to define a mouse dragged event myself,Could you give me some ideas?
I have implement a example program, here's my code,
This is my custom view which implements a mouse dragged method:

```
public class Rect extends JLabel {
private int width, height;
private String title;
public int interWidth = 1500;
public int interHeight = 1000;
private JFrame frame;
private MouseMotionAdapter myAdapter;
private MouseListener myListener;

public Rect(int width, int height, String title, JFrame frame) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.title = title;
    setText(this.title);
    this.frame = frame;
    this.myAdapter = new MouseMotionAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
            System.out.println("dragged");
            me.translatePoint(me.getComponent().getLocation().x, me.getComponent().getLocation().y);
            setLocation(me.getX(), me.getY());
            frame.repaint();
        }
    };
    this.myListener = new MouseListener(){

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("click");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("press");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("release");

        }

    };
    addMouseMotionListener(this.myAdapter);
    addMouseListener(this.myListener);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, this.width - 1, this.height - 1, 20, 20);
}

public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public MouseMotionAdapter getMyAdapter() {
    return myAdapter;
}

public MouseListener getMyListener() {
    return myListener;
}
```

}

This is the main frame contains the Rect, you can drag rect by mouse, but I want to simulate a dragged event by program:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public MainFrame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 648, 518);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    Rect rect = new Rect(120,120,"example",this);
    contentPane.add(rect);

    Robot robot = new Robot();
    Point point = new Point(200,200);
    robot.mouseMove(point.x,point.y);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseMove(300, 300);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
```

}

Comment: Try it. You would generate a mousePressed event followed by a mouseMoved event, followed by a mouseReleased event. See what happens and give us your result.

Comment: I don't know how to new a fittable MouseEvent....

Comment: Search the forum/web for example that use the Robot class.

Comment: Your original question heading stated you wanted to simulate a mouse dragged by using the `Robot` class. Have you even read the Robot API? You don't define a "mouse dragged" event. You invoke methods on the Robot. There are methods for mousePressed, mouseMoved, mouseReleased. Sorry, if that wasn't clear in my original comment. I assumed you had actually read the API and were familiar with methods of the Robot class. And if you had searched the forum/web you will find examples that use these methods. So you can test it yourself to see if it works.

Comment: If you can't get it to work then post a [mcve] that shows what you have tried.

Comment: Thank for answer, I have tried with Robot class, and I'll post my code later.

Comment: And I do search MouseEvent class ,but I can't define a right mouse dragged event myself. I'll make a simple example code represent my process work and post it later..

Comment: What is the point of this code? You are not using the Robot class. Search the forum/web for example that use the Robot class. Try something simple first like clicking on a button. Once you understand how to use the Robot to use the mousePressed/mouseReleased to do a click on a button, then you try to add the mouseMoved. Maybe it will work, maybe it won't I don't know. But I'm not going to write the code to try it. It is up to you to make an effort and write the code to see what happens.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the attention and I will Try. I try to new a MouseEvent which type is MouseDragged, I can new a MouseEvent which type is mouse pressed, I am trying...

Comment: Why do you keep talking about events??? The Robot class has `methods` that you invoke.

Comment: Sorry I just edited my code, I can use robot to move cursor in my view,but robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);seems didn't pressed on the view, Could you give me a hint or clue I should do what.

Comment: This time i use robot.mouseMove and it seems worked. Finally,Thanks for the words, I will have try hard In the future before post my questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Robot robot;
try {
    robot = new Robot();
    Point point = rect.getLocationOnScreen(); //rect is my custom view
    robot.mouseMove(point.x,point.y);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseMove(point.x + 1,point.y + 1);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);//press+move+release = drag
} catch (AWTException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```